# Programatically add "Web part gallery" in a custom web part in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, react

I have a custom web part that have different tabs. In two of the tabs/pivots I want the user to be able to add a web part from the web part gallery and to do so I need either to programatically add the web part gallery in my code, or add the specific out of the box web parts that needs to be shown (in this case the Stream web part and text web part). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to load a web part inside another web part.